# How to read column in postgres DB of data type BYTEA and encoding of compressed json using PYTHON

Tags: python, json, postgresql, compression, bytea

I have a column in postgres DB of data type bytea and encoding is of compressed_json. How can I read the values of this column and get a proper json back in Python?

Comment: The JSON is compressed how? How are you accessing the database in Python?

Comment: I am accessing the postgres db using Psycopg2 in my python code. Also, I am not sure but I think the compressed json is basically just a gzipped json

Comment: Well you will need to know for sure what compression is being used or you will not be getting far. Can you find out how the data is being entered into the column?

Comment: Sure. I just found it. It is being compressed using a GZipOutputStream in java. Not sure if this helps though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But the method gzip.compress and decompress is not showing. Maybe its a version issue with my gzip module.  Anyways, I was able to decompress using below way :

1. Convert and store the column as byte array :-

   ```
      payload = bytearray(row[0])
   ```
2. For decompressing, used below code snippet :

   ```
      fileobj = cStringIO.StringIO(payload)
      gzf = gzip.GzipFile('dummy-name', 'rb', 9, fileobj)
      decomprJson = gzf.read()
   ```

Comment: gzip.compress/decompress are available from Python 3.2+.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have time at the moment to give a complete working example. Instead I will provide an outline:

1. Read column from database

```
   data = cur.fetchone()[0]
```

2. Use Python [gzip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html) module.

`json_data = gzip.decompress(data)`

Where json_data is a bytes object.

3. Use Python json module to read json_data.

UPDATE.
Example:

```
create table js_compressed(js_fld bytea);

js_str = b'[{"one": 1, "two": 2}, {"three": 3, "four": 4}]'
js_cmp = gzip.compress(js_str)
con = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test user=aklaver host=localhost") 
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("insert into js_compressed(js_fld) values(%s)", (psycopg2.Binary(js_cmp,),))
cur.execute("select js_fld from js_compressed limit 1")
js_fld = cur.fetchone()[0]
dc_fld = gzip.decompress(js_fld).decode()
json.loads(dc_fld)
[{'one': 1, 'two': 2}, {'three': 3, 'four': 4}]
```